# Remove 1 primary key column out of 3

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a composite primary key made up from 3 columns.

I've tried to remove one of the columns (`SomeColumn1`) but I can't remove it because of it's a part of the primary key.

Then I tried this code

```
DECLARE @ConstraintName NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @ConstraintName = CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PrimaryDeneme1'

ALTER TABLE PrimaryDeneme1
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_PrimaryDeneme1;

ALTER TABLE PrimaryDeneme1
DROP COLUMN SomeColumn1
```

After that the column is removed but at the same time primary key is gone.

I want to remove a primary key column but not unset the primary key.

Comment: You can only only have 1 primairy key per table. Do you mean you have a primairy key over 3 columns?

Comment: I'm trying to remove a primary column.

Comment: @MarkBaijens Yes. I have a 3 primary key in a table. It's weird but it is

Comment: So what are you wanting to do with your existing data as you remove 1 of the PK columns?

Comment: If you found out that two columns suffice for the primary key and want to drop the unnecessary third column from it, all you need to do after dropping first the key constraint and then the column is to create a new primary key on the two columns that remain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you want to remove a column that's being referenced by a constraint of any type, you must first drop the constraint and only then you can drop the column.
In this case, Once you've dropped the constraint and the column, you must create a new primary key constraint:

```
-- Drop the primary key constraint
ALTER TABLE PrimaryDeneme1
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_PrimaryDeneme1;

-- Drop the column
ALTER TABLE PrimaryDeneme1
DROP COLUMN SomeColumn1

-- Add a new primary key constraint:
ALTER TABLE PrimaryDeneme1
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_PrimaryDeneme1 PRIMARY KEY (PkColumn1, PkColumn2);
```

Don't forget to replace `PkColumn1` and `PkColumn2` with your actual column names.

Comment: No particular advantage that I can think of but the two drops don't **must** be done in sequence. They can be combined. `ALTER TABLE PrimaryDeneme1 DROP CONSTRAINT PK_PrimaryDeneme1, COLUMN SomeColumn1` https://dbfiddle.uk/ofGaMQnf

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks for your comment, I didn't know you can do both in one statement